# How to delete WMI class

Tags: c#, wmi

I have been asked to create an application to manage instances in the WMI.

In previous version of this application the WMI class looks like this

`{String Key,String Data}`

for the new version the WMI class looks like this

`{String Key,String Data1,String Data2}`.

Now I'm facing a problem if the WMI class does exist but not in the new format. This might happen for upgrade purposes.

I want to delete the old WMI class and create new one with the new format.

How I can do this?

Comment: You should really reword your title and maybe split up your question into paragraphs.

Comment: What does this have to do with WMI (Windows management instrumentation)?

Comment: my question is what is the equivalent procedure in C# to this VB script
Dim ns, cls
ns = "NameSpace path"
cls = "ClassName"
moniker = "winmgmts:" _
   & "{" _
   & "impersonationLevel=impersonate," _
   & "authenticationLevel=PktPrivacy"_
   & "}" _
   & "!\\" _
   & ".\" _
   & ns
Set WmiService = GetObject(moniker)
WmiService.delete cls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use System.Management
your code sould look like this:

```
    void DeleteClass()
    {
        string ns, cl;
        ns = "nameSpace path";
        cl = "ClassName";
        string serverString = @"\\" + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") +ns;
        ManagementScope mScope = new ManagementScope(serverString);
        using (ManagementClass cls = new ManagementClass(mScope, new ManagementPath(cl), new ObjectGetOptions()))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection objCol = cls.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in objCol)
                {
                    obj.Delete();//cleare the instances
                }
            }
            cls.Delete();//delete the class
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @A.a you welcome, notice you need to handle error and exceptions